# How do i open a .pdf file with Drawboard PDF (MS Store APP) via command prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, cmd, contextmenu, windows-11

I am developing a Python script which starts a PDF in diffrent programms depending on the file name. But if i want to open the PDF with the Microsoft App [Drawboard PDF](https://www.drawboard.com/), the standard Powershell & Python commands only start the software and don't acutally open the file.

Using the standard context menu works fine (see picture)
[Contextmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cVbY.png)

File is opened in the Drawboard PDF Software

[Drawboard PDF open file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1mcp.png)

but as soon as I try to open the file using Powershell, Python or Cmd, only the Drawboard PDF software opens without the file.

[Drawboard PDF no opened file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFnuK.png)

**Does work:**

The PDF is open in Firefox.

```
Start-Process Firefox .\Desktop\test.pdf
```

**Does not work:**

Drawbord PDF is open without the pdf file...

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\DRAWBOARD.DRAWBOARDPDF_6.44.7.0_x64__az88965nfbvjc\Db.App.exe" ".\Desktop\test.pdf"
```

**Taskmanager command prompt:**

[Taskmanager command promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zMnF.png)

```
"C:\Programm Files\WindowsApps\DRAWBOARD.DAWBOARDPDF_6.44.7.0_x64_az88965nfbvjc\Db.App.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXng8x4fsh0hwtx18bgqjhjna1wfdk1xqy.mca
```

Drawboard PDF as default PDF viewer is not a solution.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: You need to check whether drawboard's interface is the same of not. You can open the pdf with it normally and go to Task Manager -> Details, select columns - enable "Command prompt" there. Now you'll see what the process was run as under the hood. You'll see whether argument was supplied directly or with some flag - just use the same flags

Comment: Thank you, it was a good idea, unfortunately there is also no argument for a file recognizable.

Comment: I added the task manager detail to the post.

If I described my post poorly, please tell me what I can improve to be a better part of the community.  Its my first post on stack overflow.